# Xamarin Forms: How can I test a TV XF Application?

Tags: xamarin.forms, tvos, android-tv, apple-tv

I am planning to develop a TV application which should run on `Amazon Fire TV`, `ChromeCast`, `Roku` and `Apple TV`. For this, I have created a Xamarin Forms project with Android and IOS projects. **Is that type project support all the above-mentioned devices?**

I have created 2 Android TV Emulators with different Resolution (Screenshot added below). When I run the newly created XF project on the TV emulator, nothing is showing on the emulator. Only a black screen is visible on the UI. **For running a project into a TV emulator should I add anything else?**

**Emulator List:**

[image]

**Emulator When running the Project:**

[image]

For IOS there are no TV Simulators available on my VS, only iPhone and iPad simulators are available on it. **So How can I create a TV Simulator on VS for Mac?**

**Simulator List:**

[image]

Comment: a cursory amount of research would tell you that XF does not support those platforms

Comment: @Jason I have mentioned some devices on the question, in that list which device app development is supported by XF?

Comment: None of them.  XF officially supports iOS, Android and UWP

Comment: @Jason https://blog.infernored.com/xamarin-forms-a-fire-tv-quick-start/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately , Xamarin.Forms didn't support build Application on Apple TV until now. The blog provide the steps about debug your app on Android TV but not on tvOS . If you do want to let it supports Apple TV , you should create a independent project .
[image]

Comment: What about the Amazon Fire TV, ChromeCast, and Roku devices? Is XF support or not for these devices?

Comment: You could install Google play in Forms .

Comment: Is it a Nuget package?

Comment: Yeap ! It is available in Nuget .

Comment: I checked but not found any Nuget in that name. What is the exact name? So XF support for building apps for Amazon Fire TV, ChromeCast, and Roku devices.

Comment: Check https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base/117.1.0-preview02 and https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.toxic.apps.chrome&hl=en_US.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more? We are installing the Google play NuGet package then what is the next step? What is the use of All Screen app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214575/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).